# Callout labels and Maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.3

I'm trying to create a set of labels that are callouts that I can move, manipulate and position around the edges of my map but is also tied to the attribute table data.

Is there an extension or way to do this other than converting labels to annotations?

Using arcmap 10.3.

Comment: No, there isn't.  Feature Linked Annotation is the only correct way to do this.

Comment: If you don't mind placing them 1 by 1, you can use labelling toolbar. Place it where clicked option